# SQL select columns from table where name='a statement with 2 and more word'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

When my query is:

```
select * from table_name where name='jim'
```

everything is fine.

But when my query is:

```
select * from table where ='a statement with 2 and more word'
```

For example this query:

```
select columns from table where ='jim carrey'
```

The query just considers 'jim'.  In other words, the query just considers the first word and does not consider whatever comes after that.

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd query don't make sense -- did you mean `name = ...`?

Comment: How you are saying *query just consider 'jim'* ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  For clarity, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *"where ='a statement with 2 and more word'"* - you would need to do a separate count, if that's what the question is about or a regex.

Comment: question's too unclear for my taste.

Comment: Sql Server
//
table name : books
//column : publisher 
//colum type : nvarchar(50)
//
select * from books where publisher='MS Technology'

Comment: if it is nvarchar then you need to prefix string constants with an N

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you so much @Hogan understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not work like that. If you take the following three queries:

```
select * from users where  name = 'Frank Jones'
select * from users where  name = 'Frank'
select * from users where name like 'Frank%'
```

If I run these on my SQL server database (after changing back to our real data structure) I will get  1 response to the first , the person who is actually named "Frank Jones'. I will not get 'Frank Jones III'

Since both first and last names are in the name columns if I run the second query, I will get no results.

If I run the third query I will get everyone whose first name if Frank but will not get "Jason Franks' because I only have a wildcard at the end of the phrase I am searching for. If I wanted everyone who had and portion of Frank in their name I would write this query:

```
select * from users where name like '%Frank%'
```

These are standard rules on what the various where clauses mean that apply to every database I have ever seen (although some might have a differnt wildcard symbol).

Answer (score 0):

> You don't say what platform you are using which makes answering your question harder but I will give an answer that will be close.

You need to parse the first work in the string. So

```
 SELECT aColumn 
 FROM aTable 
 WHERE name = LEFT('Jim Carrey', CHARINDEX('Jim Carrey',' '))
```

Would be an example in sql server

*The name of these functions changes for each platform.*

Comment: @AreF how does it not work???????????????????????????????????????????????